# Problems with autograd.hessian_vector_product and scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint

Tags: python-2.7, scipy, autograd

I'm trying to run a minimization problem using `scipy.optimize`, including a `NonlinearConstraint`.  I really don't want to code derivatives myself, so I'm using `autograd` to do it.  But even though I follow the exact same procedure for the arguments to `minimize` and to `NonlinearConstraint`, the first seems to work and the second doesn't.

Here's my MWE:

```
useconstraint = False

import autograd
import autograd.numpy as np
from scipy import optimize

def function(x): return x[0]**2 + x[1]**2
functionjacobian = autograd.jacobian(function)
functionhvp = autograd.hessian_vector_product(function)

def constraint(x): return np.array([x[0]**2 - x[1]**2])
constraintjacobian = autograd.jacobian(constraint)
constrainthvp = autograd.hessian_vector_product(constraint)

constraint = optimize.NonlinearConstraint(constraint, 1, np.inf, constraintjacobian, constrainthvp)

startpoint = [1, 2]

bounds = optimize.Bounds([-np.inf, -np.inf], [np.inf, np.inf])

print optimize.minimize(
  function,
  startpoint,
  method='trust-constr',
  jac=functionjacobian,
  hessp=functionhvp,
  constraints=[constraint] if useconstraint else [],
  bounds=bounds,
)
```

When I turn `useconstraint` off (at the top), it works fine and minimizes at `(0, 0)` as expected.  When I turn it on, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 29, in <module>
    bounds=bounds,
  File "/home/heshy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_minimize.py", line 613, in minimize
    callback=callback, **options)
  File "/home/heshy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_trustregion_constr/minimize_trustregion_constr.py", line 336, in _minimize_trustregion_constr
    for c in constraints]
  File "/home/heshy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_constraints.py", line 213, in __init__
    finite_diff_bounds, sparse_jacobian)
  File "/home/heshy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_differentiable_functions.py", line 343, in __init__
    self.H = hess(self.x, self.v)
  File "/home/heshy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autograd/wrap_util.py", line 20, in nary_f
    return unary_operator(unary_f, x, *nary_op_args, **nary_op_kwargs)
  File "/home/heshy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autograd/differential_operators.py", line 24, in grad
    vjp, ans = _make_vjp(fun, x)
  File "/home/heshy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autograd/core.py", line 10, in make_vjp
    end_value, end_node =  trace(start_node, fun, x)
  File "/home/heshy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autograd/tracer.py", line 10, in trace
    end_box = fun(start_box)
  File "/home/heshy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autograd/wrap_util.py", line 15, in unary_f
    return fun(*subargs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/heshy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autograd/differential_operators.py", line 88, in vector_dot_grad
    return np.tensordot(fun_grad(*args, **kwargs), vector, np.ndim(vector))
  File "/home/heshy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autograd/tracer.py", line 44, in f_wrapped
    ans = f_wrapped(*argvals, **kwargs)
  File "/home/heshy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/autograd/tracer.py", line 48, in f_wrapped
    return f_raw(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/heshy/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/numeric.py", line 1371, in tensordot
    raise ValueError("shape-mismatch for sum")
ValueError: shape-mismatch for sum
```

What am I doing wrong?  I think the issue is in the `hessian_vector_product` because I see `hess` in the error message, but I'm not sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the answer.  This was very confusing.

The `hessp` argument to `minimize` expects a function that returns the "Hessian of objective function times an arbitrary vector p" ([source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize)).  By contrast, the `hess` argument to `NonlinearConstraint` expects "A callable [that] must return the Hessian matrix of dot(fun, v)" ([source](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint.html#scipy.optimize.NonlinearConstraint)).

If you interpret the first quote like I did, "Hessian of (objective function times an arbitrary vector p)", it means pretty much the same thing as "Hessian matrix of dot(fun, v)".  I therefore assumed you could use the same `autograd` function for both.

However, the correct interpretation is "(Hessian of objective function) times an arbitrary vector p", which is completely different.  The `hessian_vector_product` function in `autograd` gives the correct result for the first, but you need a different function for the second.

Comment: So was there a solution to this, or can you not use autograd this way?